# How to limit the number of ACTIVE button checkboxes to 3 at a time?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, checkbox, bootstrap-4

**UPDATE: How do I change the ACTIVE state on Jquery to limit it to 3 Active State Buttons?**

I'm having trouble creating a simple button checkbox group, where
the user can only Select 3 Active checkbox buttons at a time.

[image: Active Button Limit to 3]

> I attempted using JQuery, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something
>   wrong. This code only works for checkboxes by themselves, but not for
>   the Active Class used in Bootstrap Checkbox Buttons. To replicate this
>   problem you need the latest bootstrap. Here's a fiddle:
>   https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/t0cswbpo/4/

Please help me figure this out, I'm a complete noob in Jquery and JS and I'm guessing that's how you solve this issue.

**JQuery:**

```
var limit = 3;

    $('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
       if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
           this.checked = false;
       }
    });
    <div class="btn-group-toggle pricing-levels-3 d-inline-block" data-toggle="button-checkbox">
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="button-checkbox">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
    </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="checkbox"> Option 4
    </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="checkbox"> Option 5
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `querySelectorAll` method and pass it a selector such as `input[type='checkbox']:checked` which will return a `NodeList` of checked checkbox elements. If that list's length is greater than your desired max then prevent the user from checking the box:

```js
const max = 3;

document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".btn-group-toggle input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > max) {
      e.target.checked = false;
      console.log(`${max} buttons are alraedy checked!`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group-toggle pricing-levels-3 d-inline-block" data-toggle="button-checkbox">


  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
  </label>



  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. When you try it with bootstrap styles it ignores the limit.

Comment: i.is.cc/opU4J2A.jpg this is what it looks like with bootstrpa styles, and your code. I can still ToggleON all the buttons

Comment: Yeah - this is really just an example of an approach you can use. You need to update the CSS selector in `querySelectorAll` so it returns the correct elements. If you have a link to a JS fiddle or something I can take a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/t0cswbpo/8/ This fiddle contains the code you provided,, check it out

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out after playing around with jQuery, I hope this answer can help others with the same problem:

This is the correct jQuery code to limit the pressing of 3 buttons, and additionally display a message that says you've reached the limit of 3 options.

Here's the **JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var limit = 3;
  $("li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($("a.active").length >= limit) {
      $("#message").slideDown();
      if($(this).hasClass("active"))
      {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
       $("#message").slideUp();
      }

    }else{
     $("#message").slideUp();
     $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mt-3 container position-relative">



    <div class="m-0 p-0 mobiletitle sentence" id="message">Please only choose 3 options.</div>

    <div class="mt-2 mt-md-2 mt-lg-3 list-group d-inline-block text-left">
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 1</a> </li>        
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 2</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 3</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 4</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 5</a> </li>

            <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 6</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 7</a> </li>
                        <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 8</a> </li>
    </div>

        <input id="register" disabled class="border-0 font-weight-bold btn-secondary text-uppercase sentence py-3 btn-lg btn-block" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>

            </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#message{display:none; color:red; margin-top:-5px!important;}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This is the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/t0cswbpo/61/